# How to use username in URL like facebook and twitter in Django project?

Tags: python, django, url, profile

I am working on django project. I am kinda learning it. So my project has user login logout functionality and I wanna add profile based user management system too. So what I wanna do is if someone is trying to access this link, I wanna show user profile

```
siteURL/username
```

so my project's urls.py file has these codes,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Robots.txt request
    url(r'^robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain")),

    # Profile related requests
    url(r'^$', include('UserProfile.urls')),

    # Home page request
    url(r'^$', include('Homepage.urls')),


    # Accounts related requests
    url(r'^accounts/', include('Accounts.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

# handling error requests for 403, 404, 500 etc

handler404 = 'errorPages.views.error404'
handler500 = 'errorPages.views.error500'
```

and my UserProfile app has url.py file and codes are,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # User Profile related requests

    url(r'^(?P<uname>.+?)/update$', User_Profile_Update.as_view()),

]
```

and my class file's codes are,

```
class HC_User_Profile_Update(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "user_profile/profile_update.html"),
```

My homepage app has urls.py file and codes are,

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page request
    url(r'^$', HomePage.as_view()),
]
```

and homepage class file,

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():

            return render(request, "homepage/home.html", {'uname': request.user.uname})
        else:
            return render(request, "homepage/home.html")
```

I am getting 404 error that Url not found. So can anyone tell me what is wrong in my urls? For now, I just wanna check that the url is rendering the html page or not. And url I am trying to access right now is

```
sitename/username/update
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you try add a slash at the end of urls.py?url(r'^(?P<uname>.+?)/update/$

Comment: @PauloPessoa, same thing. Didn't work.

Comment: what is User_Profile_Update ? can i see the view code?

Comment: That is `class HC_User_Profile_Update(TemplateView):` codes. By mistake, I have used' `HC_` at beginning, but in my file its `class User_Profile_Update(TemplateView):` codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove $ from your project's urls.py file. Update your urls.py file as

```
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Robots.txt request
    url(r'^robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain")),

    # Profile related requests
    url(r'^', include('UserProfile.urls')),

    # Home page request
    url(r'^$', include('Homepage.urls')),


    # Accounts related requests
    url(r'^accounts/', include('Accounts.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

# handling error requests for 403, 404, 500 etc

handler404 = 'errorPages.views.error404'
handler500 = 'errorPages.views.error500'
```

Hope it will work.